# TypeError: Cannot read property 'has' of undefined // Discord.js

Tags: javascript

So, I was creating a bot for my Discord server. And I got this error. Please remember that I am an amateur :). Thanks in advance, appreciate it^^.

```
 const config = require('../config.js');
 module.exports = message => {
  let client = message.client;
  if (message.author.bot) return;
  if (!message.content.startsWith(config.prefix)) return;
  let command = message.content.split(' ')[0].slice(config.prefix.length);
 let params = message.content.split(' ').slice(1);
 let cmd;
 if (client.commands.has(command)) {
   cmd = client.commands.get(command);
 } else if (client.aliases.has(command)) {
   cmd = client.commands.get(client.aliases.get(command));
 };
 if (cmd) {
   if(!message.guild) {
     if(cmd.config.guildOnly === true) {
       return;
     };
   };
   if (cmd.config.permLevel) {
     if(cmd.config.permLevel === "BOT_OWNER") {
  if(!config.geliştiriciler.includes(message.author.id)) {
       message.channel.send(`Bu komutu kullanabilmek için \`${cmd.config.permLevel}\` yetkisine sahip olmalısın.`).then(msg => msg.delete({timeout: 3000}));
       return;
  }
     }
       if(!message.member.hasPermission(cmd.config.permLevel)) {
     message.channel.send(`Bu komutu kullanabilmek için \`${cmd.config.permLevel}\` yetkisine sahip olmalısın.`).then(msg => msg.delete({timeout: 3000}));
    return;
     };
   };
   cmd.run(client, message, params);
};
};
```

Comment: Depending on which line throws the error, either `client.commands` or `client.aliases` is `undefined`.

Comment: It should be 'client.commands'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add some booleans for checking if client.commands/client.aliases is undefined.

```
if (client.commands && client.commands.has(command)) {
      cmd = client.commands.get(command);
    } else if (client.aliases && client.aliases.has(command)) {
      cmd = client.commands.get(client.aliases.get(command));
    };
```

Comment: Seems like this worked out! No errors on the console. Thanks^^

Comment: I am glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

At line no 7, please try this

```
const cmd =
  message.client.commands.get(command) ||
  message.client.commands.find(
    (cmd) => cmd.aliases && cmd.aliases.includes(command) // if you're also using aliases
  );

if (!command) return;
```

Comment: ReferenceError: cmd is not defined
I got this error from now on, so sorry if I am doing something wrong. As like I said, I am a newbie

Comment: Everyone is a newbie here bro. I just asked instead of let cmd, please try with the code I provided. Not sure it will work, but you can try. Also console.log(cmd) to chk what you are actually getting there.